# Conditions for a frame to be a local inertial frame

Tags: general-relativity, relativity

A local inertial frame is a small neighbourhood within which the laws of the special theory of relativity hold. But I have a confusion regarding what is necessary/sufficient for a GCT ($x \rightarrow x'$) to yield a local inertial frame.

- Is it necessary/sufficient that $g'_{ij}(x_0') = \delta_{ij} $?
- Is it necessary/sufficient that $\partial _k g'_{ij}(x_0') = 0$ or maybe that only the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$  needs to be zero?

Comment: If all Christoffels are zero, all first derivatives of the metric are zero. If you're not convinced, compute $\Gamma^l{}_{ij}g_{lk}+\Gamma^l{}_{ik}g_{lj}$. It's $\partial_i g_{jk}$.